# pass props to new page via react-router Link

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-props

I am trying to pass a prop `courseid` to a new page when I click the `link` whilst using `react-router-dom` But I dont seem to be able to access it. I have tried different ways I have found, but none let me access `courseid` on the new page

In `courseListItem` I have access to `props.course.id` I have a button that takes me to '/holes'

```
<Link
                        to={{
                          pathname: `/holes`, state: {courseid: props.course.id}
                          }} >
                          <button  
                            className="btn btn-primary tooltips float-left" 
                            data-placement="left" 
                            data-toggle="tooltip" 
                            data-original-title="view"
                            ><i 
                            className="fa fa-edit">

                            </i> 
                          </button>
                      </Link>
```

From what I have read, I can use `state: {courseid: props.course.id}` to pass `courseid` to the new page, and then on the new page, use `location.state.courseid` to access courseid.

Using `location.state.courseid` on the new page gives me an error `unexpected use of location`

I found a post saying to use `window.location.state.courseid` this got rid of the error but when I try and click the button to go to /holes, I get another error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'courseid')` so obviously not finding the `courseid`

Please can someone explain where I am going wrong? Or what is the best way to pass `courseid` to the new page.

`courseid` is part of a `course` object and /holes is a page that has a form on it, but I only need the id so that when I submit the form, it can send the id with the post request to save the holes entered on the form to the correct course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what type of your component `functional component` or `class component` if you write on functional component you can use `useLocation` `hooks` from `react-router-dom` if you using `class component` you should use `location` props from your component.

maybe your component be like this, its just example to access `state` on location using `useLocation`

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const Holes = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>HOLES</h1>
      <h2>{location.state.courseid}</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Holes;
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Just so I am sure what I am doing, this `courseid` passed to this page , wont be available if the page is refreshed? So if I click the link to the hole page, the courseid is passed over and accessed via location.state.courseid. but if I refresh the page, the courseid is lost and I will get an error.

Comment: yes if it refreshed the state it is gone.. i still figure it out about the best practice.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`useLocation()` hook](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation) in order to get the `location` variable that holds the state.

In case you are using Class Components, the [`location` variable](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/location) will be provided in different ways depending on how you are instantiating your `<Route {...}/>`'s

- Route component as `this.props.location`
- Route render as `({ location }) => ()`
- Route children as `({ location }) => ()`
- withRouter as `this.props.location`